# Composition of fibrations, fiber homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p: D \to B$ and $q: E \to B$ be fibrations and let $f: D \to E$ be a map such that $q \circ f = p$. If $f$ is a homotopy equivalence, does it necessarily follow that $f$ is a fiber homotopy equivalence?

Answer (score 0):

There is a more general result here. Suppose given a commutative diagram of maps

$$\begin{matrix}
D & \xrightarrow{f} & E \\
p \downarrow && \downarrow q \\
A & \xrightarrow{g}& B
\end{matrix}
$$
such that $p,q$ are fibrations and $f,g$ are homotopy equivalencies. let $k$ be any homotopy inverse of $g$, and let $H:gk \simeq 1: B \to B,\, K:kg \simeq 1: A \to A  $ be homotopies. Then there is a homotopy inverse $l$ of $f$ such that $pl=kq$ and there is a  homotopy $K': lf \simeq 1$ which  covers $K$ and a homotopy $H': fl \simeq 1$ which covers a kind of "conjugate homotopy" 
$$K + k H(g \times 1) - K(kg \times 1) . $$
In particular, the pair $(f,g)$ is a fibre homotopy equivalence. Not that if $A=B$ and $g=1$ then we can take the homotopies $H,K$ to be constant.

This result  with different notation is Theorem 3.4 in the paper

R. Brown and P.R.Heath, ``Coglueing homotopy equivalences'', *Math. Z*. 113  (1970) 313-362.

available [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/brown-heath.pdf). The main result of the paper is the dual of a glueing theorem for homotopy equivalences proved in all editions of [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html), Chapter 7.